# Best way for multiple widgets

Tags: qt, frame, mdi

I am making a GUI. In this gui I have a top level of 5 buttons. On clicking any of these buttons a screen appears. Now there are eight horizontal buttons which will have different functionality i.e different page on the above screen (One opened by top button) for each page.
There are multiple ways of doing it. Two which I have narrowed down are

1. Use a MDI window. For every top button have a subwindow and keep a stacked widget on the subwindow and change the pages of stackedwidget. And for every top window minimize and maximize the different subwindows.
2. Use different QFrame panels and have a stacked widget on each panel and show or hide whichever panel is in use.

I would like to know which of the two is better option. If there are any other better suggestions please let me know. My aim will be that there should not be much time lag during the operation due to too many screens.

Thank you... :)

Comment: What do you mean by "screen"? Top-level window or just a widget? Can you please create pictures of what you want? And it's not clear why would you need to use MDI windows.

Comment: I can't create a picture. By screen I mean on clicking a button the related i.e subwindow from MDI or a panel will appear which will contain my stacked widget to operate with the right and left hand side functional buttons..

Comment: @user2548968 You can't open gimp or paint to draw a simplistic version of your application design?

Comment: I can but I cant post it here...I created one in paint but it says I dont have enough reputation to post a photo... :(

Comment: You can always post a link to the image.